# CURL download file command adding extra bytes

Tags: curl

I am using the below curl command to download files:
`curl -i -v -o "file_name" -H "header_info" "url_to_download_the_file_from"`.

Now I am observing that the downloaded file has been injected with additional header information.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Sun, 19 Apr 2015 06:05:48 GMT

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=bhcdscb04txxGCz3dCF__W1z7v!1738481240; path=/; HttpOnly
```

As as result the downloaded file has additional bytes.
I don't want the (response) header information to be injected in the downloaded file.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the `-i` (`--include`) flag from your command to suppress HTTP header info in the output.